# Sending automatic email on future date

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote my first code on google script trying to send an automatic email when before/when/after a deadline is met. Although the first two condition work, I didn’t manage to send an email when the deadline is a future date.

**Consider the following code:**

```
function EmailReminder() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("A2:C4");
var UserData = range.getValues();
var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");

for (i in UserData){
  var row = UserData[i];
  var Contact = row[0];
  var ActionNeeded = row[1];
  var ActionDeadline = row[2];
  var ActionDeadlines = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(ActionDeadline),"GMT+1","dd/MM/yyyy"); 
  if  (ActionDeadlines  < today) { 
    MailApp.sendEmail(row[0], "Action pending for your project ","Dear PM,\n\nFor your project, the deadline to complete the following action was on " + ActionDeadline + ": \n\n*****\n\n"  + ActionNeeded + "\n\n*****\n\nKindly take appropriate action as soon as possible.");
}  
  else if (ActionDeadlines == today) { 
    MailApp.sendEmail(row[0], "Action pending for your project ","Dear PM,\n\nFor your project, the deadline to complete the following action is today: \n\n*****\n\n"  + ActionNeeded + "\n\n*****\n\nKindly take appropriate action as soon as possible.");
}  
  else if (ActionDeadlines > today) { 
    MailApp.sendEmail(row[0], "Action pending for your project ","Dear PM,\n\nFor your project, there is an upcoming deadline due on the " + ActionDeadline + ": \n\n*****\n\n"  + ActionNeeded + "\n\n*****\n\nKindly take appropriate action as soon as possible."); 
}
}
}
```

**Sample Data:**

```
Contact               ActionNeeded                  Deadline
Insert email    function for a past deadline       =today()-5 
Insert email    function for a current deadline    =today() 
Insert email    function for a future deadline     =today()+5
```

Results:

1. For deadlines with past dates: email sent is fine
2. For deadlines with today's date: email sent is fine
3. For deadlines with future dates: it gives the right ActionNeeded but it seems to be mistakenly activated by the first If condition (ActionDeadlines  < today) and not the third one (ActionDeadlines > today).
4. Lastly, the time on the email includes the hours ("Sat Mar 02 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)").

How can I keep it to dd/MM/yyyy?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)), the `formatDate()` method returns a string. Ideally, you should do Date comparison in JS with the [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

I made the following changes:
Line 5: var today = new Date();
Line 6: today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
Line 11: var ActionDeadline = new Date(row[2]);
Line 12: ActionDeadline.setHours(0,0,0,0); 
I used ActionDeadline variable in the If statement. 
This seems to solve the problem of the future date. However, deadlines that are today are not captured by the code anymore. I tried to put hours to 0 to avoid any discrepancy but without luck. Any idea? Thanks!